# Prepared Statements - Iterative query

Tags: c#, sql, iteration, prepared-statement

I have to upgrade the following code to use prepared statements:

```
OdbcCommand cmd = sql.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT [EMail] from myTable WHERE "+,
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
   if (i > 0)
   {
      cmd.CommandText += " OR ";
   }
   cmd.CommandText += "UNIQUE_ID = " + lUniqueIDS[i];
}
```

Forbid my stupid code above, it's just an example... I'm trying to fetch all the Emails of users with IDs either x, y, z, etc...

The question is - how can I rewrite it using prepared statements?
A blind naive guess would be

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
   if (i > 0)
   {
      cmd.CommandText += " OR ";
   }
   cmd.CommandText += "UNIQUE_ID = ?";
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@UNIQUE_ID", OdbcType.BigInt).Value = lUniqueIDS[i];
}
```

Should it work? Can I append the same parameter (unique_id) more than once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using positional parameters (i.e. `?` in the query, rather than `@UNIQUE_ID`) which means the names of the parameters shouldn't matter as far as the SQL is concerned. However, I wouldn't be entirely surprised to see the provider complain... and it may make diagnostics harder too. I suggest you use the index as a suffix:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@UNIQUE_ID" + i, ObdcType.BigInt).Value = lUniqueIDs[i];
```

Comment: and the original line, cmd.CommandText += "UNIQUE_ID = ?";
should remain the same?

Comment: @user611023: Assuming your query provider supports positional parameters, that should be fine.